# CinchAPIAuth Cant find it in NuGet package manager

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I apologize if its dumb question but I am been trying to fix this issue and not able to find any resources. I am working on a WINForm application and running into these errors when i try to test the file.

[List of errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mk5zQ.png)

Tried looking for NuGet File manger but I am not able to find this package.

Comment: If you have *imported* code from a third-party source and you're missing references in your code, just press `ALT+ENTER` on the underlined object(s) (or use the light bulb). Visual Studio can suggest and install the missing packages (if these are actually published)

Answer (score 0):

The CinchAPIAuth, CustomerId, Authenticator that lead to CS0246 are not some members of the published nuget package.

You need to right-click Dependencies in Solution Explorer, then click "Add Project Reference" to add the dll containing CinchAPIAuth, CustomerId, Authenticator.

If you have added the related dll, then maybe the related named control is not imported. You can place the mouse on the class or other members that reported the error, and then click "show potential fixes" in the pop-up window, which will display the namespace that your project has referenced.

[image]